# Flask Apache Start Fails with Permission Denied

Tags: apache, flask, centos7

I am trying to install Flask on my CentOS 7.9.2009 VM running Apache HTTP Server.  I've installed Python3.8 and mod_wsgi but when I attempt to start Apache I get the below Permissioned denied when loading the mod_wsgi. I've checked multiple blogs and forums and cannot find a resolution. Any idea why I am getting this error?

Error: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/02-wsgi.conf: Cannot load /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so into server: /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

I installed python3.8 from source using `./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"` but I am still getting the above permission denied error.

Below is how my app.conf file looks like and also output of mod_wsgi module-config.

**app.conf:**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
```

**mod_wsgi module-config:**

```
[myuser@mycentos conf.d]$ mod_wsgi-express module-config
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py38.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/usr/local"
```

I get the error when I try to start Apache - sudo systemctl start httpd.

Comment: Apache normally runs under its own user which is called apache (if not httpd). So it does not have access to the files belonging to other users. It's as simple as that. Prefer a system-wide install of mod_wsgi. For example [this tutorial](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/web-development/use-mod-wsgi-to-run-python-as-a-web-application-on-centos-7/) shows: `sudo yum install mod_wsgi`. Try not to install software from source when there is a package available for your distro. And perhaps, look for a good tutorial. I quoted one but it may not be comprehensive.

Comment: @Kate I've tried that as well but ran into a diff problem. When I do a yum install Apache is not using the Python3.8 version. From the error logs it is using python3.6 (`mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.6 configured`) where I do not have flask installed. This causes an import error. I would use this method if I can point Apache to Python3.8. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: I suggest you make a proper install of uwsgi, preferably from distribution packages using yum/dnf. It just isn't installed in an appropriate place where Apache could load it. It's always possible to install a higher version of Python after. Perhaps this post can help too: [How to change my Python version on CentOS for scripts executed via apache?](https://serverfault.com/q/882586/377666)

Answer (score 0):

The permission issue was because of SELinux enabled/enforced on my system. I reached out to one of the mod_wsgi source code authors and he pointed me to check this.  For now disabling this resolved my immediate issue. If others have suggestions to resolve this without turning it off please suggest.

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```